# How do I add a version number to a jQuery UI Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I have created a new jQuery UI Widget and wanted to add a version so that if my API changes in the future, users can react appropriately based on the stated version of the widget.  In the core widgets the developers used `$.extend()` to add a public version variable:

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog, {
    version: "1.8.11",
    ...
});
```

Is this the appropriate method for adding a version identifier to my own widget or should I just include the variable as part of the original widget definition?

Comment: I used jqueryui. jquerui include the version number in the comments of the js file. I think you could do the same.

Comment: The comments are not discoverable by user code.  That is the reason that the version property exists.  If you look at the source for jQueryUI you can see the version property added to various widgets and even the root ui namespace using the `$.extend()` method.  I don't fully understand why it is done this way and want to make sure I am not missing something critical when building my own widget.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "just include the variable as part of the original widget definition"? Because in my understanding it is the exact same thing as the method described with code - except that the one with `$.extend()` adds it to the object, while the other with `$.widget()` adds it to the object's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

how about `$.ui.dialog.version`?

I think you best should use somehting like `window.myvar={dielog: '1.0',...}` doing it manually :) coz most of the time you'd get the ui version as suppose to dialog version... :) but hope that solves your problem